# How to segregate first three XML tags and create an XML

Tags: xml, xslt

How to select first 3 tags from XML and loop it till the XML ends?

The first three tags represent one block of information followed by the other one

FYI, its XSLT 2.0

Please note the input XML may contain more than 6 records.
Input XML

```
<tokens>
   <token>"lvs1-001"</token>
   <token>"Deleted"</token>
   <token>"101.34.76.84"</token>
   <token>"lvs1-002"</token>
   <token>"Deleted"</token>
   <token>"101.62.93.75"</token>
</tokens>
```

Expected one:

```
<xml>
  <tokens>
    <token>lvs1-001</token>
    <token>Deleted</token>
    <token>101.34.76.84</token>
  </tokens>
  <tokens>
    <token>lvs1-002</token>
    <token>Deleted</token>
    <token>101.62.93.75</token>
  </tokens>
  <tokens>
  </tokens>
  <tokens>
  </tokens>
</xml>
```

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0 (or 3.0)?

Comment: The expected output has two empty `<tokens></tokens>` tags at the end. Is this intentional?

Comment: It's not intentional, just wanted to inform that we may have more than 6 entries and every 3 tag should be under <tokens></tokens>

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial in **XSLT 2.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/tokens">
    <xml>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="token" group-by="(position()-1) idiv 3">
            <tokens>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />
            </tokens>       
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xml>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry for the mismatch, the studio is 7.8 version with XSLT 1.0 editor.  Please find the error response below: Caused by:
      Summary: Could not find function: current-group

     Caused by:
       Summary: Could not find function: current-group

Comment: Seriously? <eyes rolling> See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21126085/3016153

Comment: the input XML is different in the link you provided, it doesn't match the given input XML. Can you please help me out here.

Comment: @BAO_1989 So what if the input is different? The principle is the same. Here's even simpler method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45515332/3016153

Comment: Can you please help me to get a thread which explains call template and apply template in XSLT

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Try a tutorial or a book.

Answer (score -1):

As per the input below:

```
<tokens>
    <token>"lvs1-001"</token>
    <token>"Deleted"</token>
    <token>"101.34.76.84"</token>
    <token>"lvs1-002"</token>
    <token>"Deleted"</token>
    <token>"101.62.93.75"</token>
     </tokens>
```

Code to create required output:

```
<xml>
        <tokens>    
            <xsl:for-each select="tokens/token">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position() &lt;= 3">
                        <token><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" /></token>
                    </xsl:when>
                 </xsl:choose> 
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tokens>
        <tokens>    
             <xsl:for-each select="tokens/token">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position() &gt; 3">
                        <token><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" /></token>
                    </xsl:when>
                 </xsl:choose> 
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tokens>
    </xml>
```

Result:

```
<xml>
<tokens>
    <token>"lvs1-001"</token>
    <token>"Deleted"</token>
    <token>"101.34.76.84"</token>
</tokens>
<tokens>
    <token>"lvs1-002"</token>
    <token>"Deleted"</token>
    <token>"101.62.93.75"</token>
</tokens>
```

Comment: I don't think this is helping. And it's ill-formed XML to boot.

Comment: The given XML is not formatted properly. But It can be structured to get the requirements.

Comment: The given XML is well-formed. The problem with your current answer is that you assume there will be exactly 6 tokens in the inputs. The way I understand the question is that there can be any number of groups of three - otherwise they would not ask how to "loop it till the XML ends".

Comment: Yes, agreed. But I assumed as per the 1st two lines of question (i.e **1** How to select first 3 tags from XML) and (**2** The first three tags represent one block of information followed by the other one)

Comment: Assume the given XML has more than 6 records. Going by the result I see the response as:<xml>
  <tokens>
    <token>"lvs1-plcws-001.paypalcorp.com"</token>
    <token>"Deleted"</token>
    <token>"10.185.254.56"</token>
  </tokens>
  <tokens>
    <token>"lvs1-plcws-002.paypalcorp.com"</token>
    <token>"Deleted"</token>
    <token>"10.185.254.57"</token>
    <token>"lvs1-plcws-003.paypalcorp.com"</token>
    <token>"Deleted"</token>
    <token>"10.185.254.58"</token>
  </tokens>
</xml>

Comment: @BAO_1989 Please post your clarifications in the question itself, not in comments to an answer. More importantly, clarify which version of XSLT your processor supports, as this is crucial when dealing with grouping problems (which this is).